# Email Template ignores Word Wrapping within matrix fields

Tags: expresso-store, devdemon

In the **order confirmation email template** i have set **Word Wrapping** to "**on**" and **Email Formatting** to "**Plain Text**".

however inside this template with:

```
{exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}" show_future_entries="yes"}
{matrix_field}
{matrix_field_col_name}.
{/matrix_field}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

i get:

```
matrix_field_col_content_1.matrix_field_col_content_2.matrix_field_col_content_3.
```

but it should be:

```
matrix_field_col_content_1.
matrix_field_col_content_2.
matrix_field_col_content_3.
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're inside a matrix field it is simply spitting them out in one line so it is working as expected. The word-wrap function is not being triggered because it's one long word.

To have your items output to a new line, simply add `\r\n` immediately after the '.'

Comment: unfortunately this outputs `rn` and not a new line.

Comment: In that case place a carriage return in your code after the `.`